# Is there a better way to create a randomizer web domain name generator?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i want to ask whether there is a better solution to get a much more randomize output. this is my code.

```
Combined = open("dictionaries/Combined.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
Example = open("dictionaries/examples.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
```

I first opened the dictionary and then the output is going to be written on a `.txt` file called `example.txt`. then i do this next.

```
for web_Test in Combined:
    Combined_result = re.search(r"([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*", web_Test)
    Text_Test = (Combined_result.group())
    Example.write((Text_Test+'.web'+'.co.id'+"\n"))
    #print(Text+'.bni'+'.co.id')
```

My idea is that i used the `Combined.txt` file and create 5 different combination `Example.write((Text_Test+'.web'+'.co.id'+"\n"))` from this code so that there would be much more text output variety.

This is what's inside the combined text file

[image: Combined.txt]

After that i print out the output and this is what i got.

```
with open("dictionaries/examples.txt") as f:
    websamples = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
print (websamples)

['auth.web.co.id',
 'access.web.co.id',
 'account.web.co.id',
 'admin.web.co.id',
 'agree.web.co.id',
 'blue.web.co.id',
 'business.web.co.id',
 'cdn.web.co.id',
 'choose.web.co.id',
 'claim.web.co.id',
 'cl.web.co.id',
 'click.web.co.id',
 'confirm.web.co.id',
 'confirmation.web.co.id',
 'connect.web.co.id',
 'download.web.co.id',
 'enroll.web.co.id',
 'find.web.co.id',
 'group.web.co.id',
 'http.web.co.id',
 'https.web.co.id',
 'https-www.web.co.id',
 'install.web.co.id']
```

Now after I saw the output, I just realized that the output is not really random enough. It just straight up took the text from the combined text file one by one and just drop it there. even if i made a different combination of this line `Example.write((Text_Test+'.web'+'.co.id'+"\n"))` it would be quite a waste of time. Is there a better way where I can do a randomized generated website domain?

For example I want the output that I got is `install.web.co.id`, but I want a more randomized output like `web.install.co.id` or `install.web.install.co.id` where it just took the words from the text and i add the web as the middle part and create a more website domain name variety.

Thx!

Comment: What exactly should your output look like? Currently there is nothing random about your selection.

Comment: i want the output to be more randomized than the current one, the output that i have right now is too straight forward. i want to have more output combination like for example right now the output is `install.web.co.id`. but i want to have a different combination like for example `web.install.co.id` or `web.install.web.co.id` @Ovski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the random.choice statement to select a random value from a list.
In my example you can also set the amount of results and subdomains.

BTW: You might reconsider using http and https as part of subdomains. That might be very confusing

```
my_list = ['access',
           'account',
           'admin',
           'agree',
           'blue',
           'business',
           'cdn',
           'choose',
           'claim',
           'cl',
           'click',
           'confirm',
           'confirmation',
           'connect',
           'download',
           'enroll',
           'find',
           'group',
           'http',
           'https',
           'https',
           'install'
           'web',
           ]

suffix = 'co.id'

output_count = 10
subdomain_count = 2
for i in range(output_count):
    out = []
    for j in range(subdomain_count):
        out.append(random.choice(my_list))
    out.append(suffix)
    print('.'.join(out))
```

output:

```
business.enroll.co.id
connect.confirmation.co.id
cdn.choose.co.id
http.cdn.co.id
choose.http.co.id
connect.cdn.co.id
group.admin.co.id
cdn.https.co.id
blue.click.co.id
group.cdn.co.id
```

Comment: okay i like this answer, but if i want another fixed word in the middle for example the word web in the middle would the code look like this? 
word = web
`output_count = 10
subdomain_count = 2
for i in range(output_count):
    out = []
    for j in range(subdomain_count):
        out.append(random.choice(my_list))
    out.append(word)
    out.append(suffix)
    print('.'.join(out))`
so it would output something like `group.admin.web.co.id`?

Comment: And also if i want to alternate instead of using `.` and i want to add `-` or `_` should i add another `print('-'.join(out))` or `print('_'.join(out) to the code? and also where is the `.join` came from the random library?

Comment: yes, you can add more strings to out for example out.append('myword') inside the for loop. ''.join is a method of string. it is used to to concatenate a list by a string delimiter